# Input date on date field of a website and click on view report button

Tags: html, excel, vba

I've used VBA but never for scraping website so I'm a beginner.
What I'm trying is to use VBA to go to my SSRS website from work, input the date for the report and run it. I've tried my best to code it but it keeps giving me

> Run Error Time 91: Object Variable or With block Variable not set.

Below is my code

```
Sub AgingReport()    
    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim ReportDate As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

     IE.navigate "www.example.com"
        IE.navigate 
        IE.Visible = True
      Application.Wait Now + #12:00:04 AM#

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

    Set ReportDate = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl09_txtValue")
        ReportDate.Value = "06/28/2019"

    HTMLDoc.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00").Click     
End Sub
```

Below is the HTML. Please let me know how I can approve the code.

HTML For Date Field

```
<input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl09$txtValue" class="null" 
id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl09_txtValue" onkeypress="if 
(WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl09$txtValue\',\'\')', 0)" type="text" size="28">
```

Here's the HTML for the the button that is code as input

```
<input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl00" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00" type="submit" value="View Report">
```

Comment: which line does the error occur on? Is the date input or does it fail before then?

Comment: The error is for both. I tried them separately.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed some of your code and added one HTML Button Element

Hope it helps!

```
Sub AgingReport()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim ReportDate As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HtmlButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

 IE.navigate "www.example.com"
    IE.navigate 
    IE.Visible = True
  Application.Wait Now + #12:00:04 AM#

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

Set ReportDate = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl09_txtValue")
    ReportDate.Value = "06/28/2019"

Set HtmlButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00")
HtmlButton.Click

End Sub
```